# How to match a string, for which a specific method is invoked, via regex?

Tags: regex

```
Regex: \"(.+?)\"\.Localize\(\)

Text: ModelState.AddModelError("Property", "Invalid property.".Localize());
```

Example:

http://regex101.com/r/aY5jK2

Currently the text `Property", "Invalid property.` gets matched. How do i match just the `Invalid property` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\"([^"]+?)\"\.Localize\(\)
```

[Demo Here](http://regex101.com/r/kE1tS7)

Comment: Same answer. I'll delete mine :P +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(")([^"]+)\1(?=\.Localize\(\))
```

Group 2 will contain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Dante, Keep your regex that's working a simply add a space (`\s`) before the quote:

```
\s\"(.*?)\"\.Localize\(\)
```

<kbd>***[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pT6rZ6)***</kbd>

***REGEX EXPLANATION:***

```
\s\"(.*?)\"\.Localize\(\)

Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, form feed) «\s»
Match the character “"” literally «\"»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “"” literally «\"»
Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the character string “Localize” literally (case insensitive) «Localize»
Match the character “(” literally «\(»
Match the character “)” literally «\)»
```